# Making subfigures have captions like standard figures

Tags: subfloats

I have used subfigures to layout my figures in the way I would like, but I would like them to have captions as if they were standard figures. IE, Figure 1, Figure 2... Is there a way of doing this?

EDIT:
Here is how I am using subfigures.

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{center} \subfigure[Figure 1]{\includegraphics[width=\figwidth\textwidth]{1.png}}
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=\figwidth\textwidth]{3.png}}\\
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=\figwidth\textwidth]{4a.png}}
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=\figwidth\textwidth]{4b.png}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Can you please make an example of how you're doing it?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about precisely how you'd like to lay out your figures. E.g., do you want them to be side by side? Are they roughly equally wide?

Comment: I have added one. The first subfigure is captioned as "(a) Figure 1". I would like to remove the "(a)".

Comment: I am happy with how my code lays out the subfigures.

Comment: It might make more sense to avoid `subfigures` and just use `minipage`s with `\caption` instead...

Comment: What's the definition of `\figwidth`? Which figure (and subfigure) packages do you load? Would I be correct in surmising that only one of the four (sub)figures is supposed to have a caption?

Comment: `\figwidth` is defined as 0.4. Its true that `minipages` would do it. Is there anyway to just remove the `(a)`?

Comment: The easiest way to drop the `(a)` is simply not using `\subfigure` but the naked `\includegraphics{...}` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sub-figures should get ordinary captions like "Figure 1" one could either use `\captionbox` offered by the `caption` package (which will align the sub-figures by their first caption line), or use `\parbox` or `minipage` with alignment parameter.

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newcommand\figwidth{0.4}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\captionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\figwidth\textwidth]{1.png}}
\captionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\figwidth\textwidth]{3.png}}\\[2ex]
\captionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\figwidth\textwidth]{4a.png}}
\captionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=\figwidth\textwidth]{4b.png}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\parbox[b]{\figwidth\textwidth}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{1.png}
  \caption{}}
% or \begin{minipage}[b]{\figwidth\textwidth}...\end{minipage}
\parbox[b]{\figwidth\textwidth}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{3.png}
  \caption{}}\\[2ex]
\parbox[b]{\figwidth\textwidth}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{4a.png}
  \caption{}}
\parbox[b]{\figwidth\textwidth}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{4b.png}
  \caption{}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Unfortunately `\captionbox` isn't documented yet but its syntax is identical to `\subcaptionbox` documented within the `subcaption` package documentation.)

Comment: Thank you, that works great, but when I compile it, the figures are labelled as `Figure 1:`. Is there a way to remove the colon?

Comment: When using the `caption` package there should be no colon since the `caption` package suppresses the colon automatically if there is no caption text given. So are you sure you get a colon when compiling my example document given in my answer?